# how to set MenuItem be <a> inside <li>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI.

I want to make some **popover** and saw `Menu` and `MenuItem` in [Menu Demo](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/). They are perfect except for one thing. I want the menu item to be **link**.

By default `MenuItem` is `li`, (I think) because `Menu` is `ul`. But it is not so hard that make an item **link** by setting `component="a"` or `component={RouterLink}`. But in this case, they lose `li`.

For **Screen Reader** like program, I heard that using an **appropriate** Html tag is important. (It is called **Semantic Web**. Right?)

In this perspective, I want to menu items to be `a` inside `li`.

-- **Trial** --

```
<MenuItem>
  <a>link text</a>
</MenuItem>
```

`a` is inside `li`. But it looks different from the case below.

```
<MenuItem component="a" href="/">
  link text
</MenuItem>
```

Then, I try

```
<MenuItem>
  <a style={{all: "inherit"}}>
    link text
  </a>
</MenuItem>
```

It looks satisfactory, but the color changes after clicking it, (I think) because `a:visited { color: ...; }` is not inherited.

Finally I tried

```
<li>
  <MenuItem component="a" href"/">
    link text
  </MenuItem>
</li>
```

Yeah. It solves all problems. But, what if I forget to add `li`?
My menu contains many items. Some of them are **link** and others are not. Then should I add `li` directly by distinguishing only the cases of **link**?

-- **Question** --
Is my solution is best? How about you? Please share your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically, `MenuItem` is more suitable for `li` because it represents an item in a list. The `component` props's default value of `MenuItem` is [`'li'`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/6e666a6ea9ed646e946211c9bfe6621f3a549471/packages/material-ui/src/MenuItem/MenuItem.js#L57) after all. So I'd go for:

```js
<MenuItem>
  <a style={{all: "inherit"}}>
    link text
  </a>
</MenuItem>
```

> But, what if I forget to add li?

That's one reason to use React, you can easily de-duplicate part of your components by creating another component and reuse it:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& a:visited": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  }
}));

function MenuItemLink({ children, href, onClick }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MenuItem onClick={onClick} className={classes.root}>
      <a href={href}>{children}</a>
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
```

```js
<Menu
  id="simple-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={handleClose}
>
  <MenuItemLink href="/" onClick={handleClose}>
    Profile
  </MenuItemLink>
  <MenuItemLink href="/" onClick={handleClose}>
    My account
  </MenuItemLink>
  <MenuItemLink href="/" onClick={handleClose}>
    Logout
  </MenuItemLink>
</Menu>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66998696/how-to-set-menuitem-be-a-inside-li]

Comment: An issue with this approach is the `a` tag isn't the same width as the `MenuItem` due to the padding, so a user must precisely click the text for the link to work.